# C/C++ malloc/free. Using one pointer for many allocations - bad idea?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Apologies if this is a silly question - I've been self-teaching C++ and am currently writing a memory manager as an exercise for myself, but I'm not clear on what happens under the hood when I'm calling malloc and free. I've provided some skeleton code below that hopefully illustrates my question a little better.

I have overriden the global new and delete operators to call into the Alloc(size_t) and Free(void*) methods of a MemoryManager class and have set up a few memory pools that are working very well. However, I allow one of my pools to grow when it needs to. This pool is initialized by allocating some heap memory to a pointer: char* mPoolAllocator.

My question is basically: When I grow my pool, is it safe to use the same pointer (mPoolAllocator) to allocate some new heap memory? What happens when I call free(mPoolAllocator) in ~MemoryManager() below? Does the default memory manager keep track of every bit of heap memory I've allocated using this pointer and allow me to free them all in one call to free, or is it simply freeing the block beginning at the address that the pointer was last set to?

The code below is only an illustration and is nowhere near to how my MemoryManager class works: I'm primarily looking for feedback on malloc() and free().

.....................................................................................................................................................................
class MemoryManager

```
class MemoryManager
{
    public:
        MemoryManager();
        ~MemoryManager();

        void* Alloc(size_t size);
        void Free(void* address);

    private:
        size_t  mFreeMemory;                // unallocated memory left
        char*   mPoolAllocator,             // used to alloc memory from the heap
            *   mUnallocated;               // points to front of free blocks linked list

        void    ExtendPool();               // extends pool, increasing available memory

        void*   GetBlock(size_t size);      // returns heap address sufficient for and object of size
}
```

.

```
void* MemoryManager::Alloc(size_t size)
{
    /* If there is free memory */
    if(size <= mFreeMemory)
    {
        return GetBlock(size);
    }
    else                                    // else create new free memory
    {
        ExtendPool();
        return GetBlock(size);
    }
}
```

.

```
void MemoryManager::ExtendPool()
{
    mPoolAllocator = (char*)malloc(POOL_EXTEND_SIZE);

    // some calls to functions that split the extended pool into blocks

    mUnallocated = mPoolAllocator;          // point to the next unallocated memory block (beginning of extended pool)
}
```

.

```
MemoryManager::~MemoryManager()
{
    free(mPoolAllocator);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that leaks memory.

Each return value from `malloc()` must be used as an argument in a distinct call to`free()`.  For this usage, look into `realloc()` which will make it work more like you expect, since it allows you to grow an already-allocated piece of heap memory.

There is no trace in the `mPoolAllocator` variable of the previous pointers returned from `malloc()`.

Also, in C++, shouldn't you use `new[]` to allocate arrays of bytes?

Comment: Just to add to this, have a look at using `realloc` too, it could be useful in this case, although you should be using new/free in C++-land.

Comment: wouldn't new[] be used when you allocate an array of things that need individual constructors/destructors ?

Comment: @slugonamission I strongly advise against realloc in the case of a memory manager, as the performance hit from reallocating any sizable block of memory is huge, and also any pointers to his managed heap will become dangling when the block is moved, unless he has a reliable update for them (reliable being the key word).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, answered the question perfectly. The reason I haven't used new to allocate an array of bytes was because I've overriden the global new operators, using them to wrap calls into my MemoryManager::Alloc(size_t) method. Perhaps that's not a great idea, but it's a quick way to allow me to add the memory manager to old projects without no extra work needed. Please correct me if I'm doing something stupid.